# Taking large netcdf and converting it to interpolated values in different set of coordinates?

Tags: r, coordinate-system, interpolation, batch, netcdf

I've got a large netcdf (a small portion of the data is [here](http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/SOURCES/.USGS/.ADDS/.NDVI/.NDVIe/.dekadal/.maximum/.NDVI/T/16350.0/16381.0/RANGE/y/-4604000.0/4604000.0/RANGEEDGES/data.cdf)) with the data in an even grid associated with an Albers Equal Area Conic projection.  I've got the corresponding latitudes and longitudes [here](http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/SOURCES/.USGS/.ADDS/.NDVI/.NDVIe/.dekadal/.maximum/lat/data.cdf) and [here](http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/SOURCES/.USGS/.ADDS/.NDVI/.NDVIe/.dekadal/.maximum/lon/data.cdf).

I want to take the information in this netcdf, and get interpolated values along a regular lat/lon grid, from 18.2W to 53E and 32.8S to 20N.  For output, I'd like a 3-dimensional array with the x, y, and z axes being lon, lat, and time.  Or a set of rasters that I can coerce to a 3d array in R.

How can this be done?

I know that I could write an R script where for each point in my regular lat/lon grid I identify the four nearest surrounding Albers points and take their inverse-euclidian-distance-weighted average.  But this will be painfully slow to compute and difficult to program.

Are there any programs or tools that can help me to batch-interpolate a netcdf with a deep time dimension?

I'll have >100 of these to do, and each grid is 1152x1152.

I seek solutions in R, or anything that can be run in some sort of batch mode.

---

This was a case where I simply didn't know the names of the tools to use.  Apparently, the "projectRaster" function in the `raster` package (which relies on gdal) does what I need once I coerce my netcdf slices into raster objects.  I had to do a bit of digging in metadata and obscure documentation to figure out proj4 syntax, but that was the extent of the difficulties.

Comment: Use the raster package, you can reproject/resample the whole thing in one step using raster's cunning tricks. But, I would question *why* you really need to reinterpolate the thing, do you really need to do that?

Comment: I've got rainfall data on a regular .1x.1 degree grid, and I want to put it into a data frame with NDVI data.  Will look into the raster package.  Any hints on which particular functions do it?

Comment: Also, is "reproject" what I want?  I'm not sure it is -- I want a data frame, not a picture.

Comment: Use extract with your lonlat points as SpatialPoints, extract will transform automatically. But there is a lot here to unpack if you are not usedto it

Comment: Resampling a grid with a simple linear procedure like IDW (or, better, bilinear interpolation) that uses a small local neighborhood is a sparse matrix multiplication--and therefore is reasonably fast to execute in almost any language. Setting it up takes only a few dozen lines of code in `R` and so is not hard to program or debug.  As @radouxju suggests, though, you don't have to re-invent the wheel: use a GIS (or GIS utility like GDAL) to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for another software that manages well the large, I suggest to use gdal.

[gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) will do exactly what you want in a single command line.